# Sum two column values together in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query to get the Win  7 and Win 10 count in SCCM. Everything is working fine but Output is not coming the way I wanted.

**Current Output**

```
DeploymentName  CollectionName  Available   Deadline    ReportTime  W10     W7
WKS 2019-10     WKS 2019-10     20:23.0     00:00.0      18:00.0    14116   0
WKS 2019-10     WKS 2019-10     20:23.0     00:00.0      18:00.0      27    0
WKS 2019-10     WKS 2019-10     20:23.0     00:00.0      18:00.0      0     2886
WKS 2019-10     WKS 2019-10     20:23.0     00:00.0      18:00.0      0      1
```

**Expected Output**

```
DeploymentName  CollectionName  Available   Deadline    ReportTime  W10     W7
WKS 2019-10     WKS 2019-10     20:23.0     00:00.0      18:00.0    14143   2887
```

Query which i have created.

```
SELECT 
CIA.AssignmentName as DeploymentName, CIA.CollectionName as CollectionName, CIA.CreationTime as Available,
CIA.EnforcementDeadline as Deadline, CIA.StartTime as ReportTime, --OPSYS.Caption0 as [Operating System],
--COUNT(*) AS 'Count' ,
sum ( CASE 
      WHEN  OPSYS.Caption0 = 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise' or OPSYS.Caption0 = 'Microsoft Windows 10 Pro' THEN  1 else 0
      END  ) As 'W10',
sum ( CASE 
      WHEN  OPSYS.Caption0 = 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise' or OPSYS.Caption0 = 'Microsoft Windows 7 Entreprise' THEN  1 else 0
      END  ) As 'W7'

FROM v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM  OPSYS 
inner join V_R_System  sys on OPSYS.ResourceID=sys.ResourceID
Inner join v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on FCM.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
--Inner join v_Collection COL on fcm.CollectionID =  col.CollectionID
inner join v_CIAssignment CIA on CIA.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID
WHERE
CIA.AssignmentName =  'WKS 2019-10 '
group by  CIA.AssignmentName, CIA.CollectionName, CIA.CreationTime,
CIA.EnforcementDeadline, CIA.StartTime, OPSYS.Caption0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you grouping by columns that are in your aggregations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the caption from the `GROUP BY`:

```
group by CIA.AssignmentName, CIA.CollectionName, CIA.CreationTime,
        CIA.EnforcementDeadline, CIA.StartTime
```